# Work on application and library simultaneously?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to java programming and I would like to work on some kind of game engine / lib. Just as a hobby project / experiment. I would like to make some sort of library with classes and utility functions to be able to re-use some generic game code and then a seperate application where I would build the actual game.

I am using intelliJ as an IDE. I was wondering if I could use, change and test a library with an application at the same time and how I would do this?

Comment: Create a library project and a game project, then add the library project as a dependency for the game project. Eventually, you will want to become familiar with dependency management and tools like Maven.

Comment: Thank you, Perception, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects here. The technical: How does it work? The organisational: Is it a good idea?

The technical is quite easy. You just create different projects. The application project depends on the library project. Libraries are packaged as jars typically. Easiest would be to use a tool that supports you with dependencies and different versions of the library. I would recommend [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for this.

The second question is harder and probably belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ as it is more of a philosophical kind and no definitive answer exists. In my point of view it is a bad idea to develop a library and a product at the same time. Specificals of your product will slip into the library, you will get problems with priorities.

That is, when you are developing a library that should be used or published independently of your application. Modularisation of an application is another cup of tea, but could be done with the same tools. With Maven you would setup a multi module project then.

Comment: Thanks, dependencies was what I was looking for. I got it to work!

As this is a personal experiment I don't have questions regarding the organisatorial, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a library? A JAR right, a JAR contains a set of classes, what you would do is to "use, change and test" the classes you would like to make a library and when everything is done, you package it as a JAR and there you are done! If you want the JAR to be created everytime you "build" try using Maven or Ant that does these packaging tasks for you automatically. Maven is more powerful and you would love to see that it mainly does "dependency management" and your library is the dependency for your project.